# "Where to buy" questions

Tags: discussion

See https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/looking-for-mare-nostrum

Is this something we want to support here?

Answer (score 7):

**No**,

These questions should be closed as too localized.

- The answer is only valid for a limited period of time
- The need is specific to one person.

Comment: When the question is "where do I buy this particular game", I agree. But the more generic "where do I buy out of print games" should have a question with some useful answers (i.e. look for sellers/traders on boardgamegeek, amongst other answers).

Answer (score 3):

I would say in the general case no:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

However in extreme circumstances -- say, the game is extraordinarily rare or very special in some way -- it *might* be OK, but that should be super rare.

Comment: I think that sounds fare.

Answer (score 2):

The last thing we want is a million questions "where can I buy game X" with exactly the same answer.  Is there a FAQ with links to boardgamegeek and other such useful places?  If not, maybe someone could create one, and point all "where to buy" requests there, before closing the question.

Comment: I think you and @Viktor are heading down the same path, and I agree with you.  It sounds like a good use of community wiki to maintain a list of OOP boardgame sellers.  If a question gets created, I'll CW it.  (Or if someone flags an old question that might fit)

Comment: I'm 100% with Viktor and TheSun here; I've created a community wiki question for users to update.  Do we want to migrate the Mare Nostrum question there, or close it and point to our question?

Comment: @little - yea, perhaps we could dup all such questions to the generic in the future?  Then delete them after a while, I don't see a need to keep individual game queries around forever.

Comment: @Pat -- duly noted.  I've gone ahead and closed the original question, and pointed Xavier to our new question.  I've also included my original answer as a comment so he has somewhere to start.