# Should "where should I sell" questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion

I've already seen the answer for ["Where to buy" questions](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/where-to-buy-questions) and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/.

They both say we shouldn't allow those questions.  According to the blog, it is also in the Super Users FAQ.

Does the same apply to "where should I sell" questions?  The situation isn't identical, and isn't *necessarily* always as subjective.

Here's such a question:

- [Where can I sell my Magic: The Gathering cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/where-can-i-sell-my-magic-the-gathering-cards)